# See different actions in Google Analytics when the same page title is used for multiple pages

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, analytics, web-applications

I work for a company that has a self-service web portal. Most transactions on this portal are in wizard format and broken down by steps. In some cases, the same Page Title may be used for a Step and it's related sub-steps.

Examples:

1. Step 1 - Look up user's account

   - By username, by password, or both
2. Step 1 - Look up user's account

   - User's email address was found, but user needs to enter further information to identify the account

Is there a way to know the difference between #1 and #2 in GA? Unfortunately, in most cases they also have the same URL within the portal. Or does the portal need to be re-architected?

Comment: Maybe they are using $ _POST or $ _GET to identify it each part of the page so load different items depending on the situation.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Google Analytics noted page titles or allowed you to report by page title.   I know that you can see differences by URL.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to add a hash value to the URL to differentiate between the different screens such as `www.example.com/wizard/lookup#username` and `www.example.com/wizard/lookup#more-info`. Once you have this linking scheme in place you can push a new pageview event to Google Analytics using...

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
    'page': location.pathname + location.search  + location.hash
});
```

And what that code will do is push the complete URL including the location hash as a new pageview to Google (you would do this instead of the default pageview code which does not include the location hash). That would then give you the listing as two separate URL's in GA without needing to do anything fancy.